# Opening a shadowbox.js popup window using a hash

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'd like to do is put an  anchor tag on an element that will direct to a different website of mine, and I'd like to designate a hash so that a shadowbox.js popup window will open up all in one click.

The link would look something like this:

```
<a href="mysecondwebsite.html#popup"><img src="hellostackoverflow.png"></a>
```

and clicking on that link would open up "mysecondwebsite.html" and open the shadowbox.js pop up on that page.

It sounds easy enough, but I'm not sure if it's possible.. any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that runs at page load on your new page just needs to look at `window.location.hash` and activate any popups indicated by its value (you might have to also scroll the window back to the top before activating the popup).

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean. The popup is activated by clicking on a specific div but is still a javascript item, and I'm not sure how to replicate that using hash.. In particular I don't know what window.location.hash means in your context or why scrolling is relevant

Comment: When you load `mysecondwebsite.html#popup`, `window.location.hash` will contain "#popup". The code that runs on page load can use that value to determine which popup to open (you won't be able to open a popup located in the site that contains the link, since that site will be replaced).

Comment: Let's take a step back. I don't of any other way to trigger the popup, I guess that would be a better question to ask. I'm not sure if placing a hash in the link will open it, I don't understand the mechanism behind it. Please excuse my ignorance

Comment: Do you know how to initiate a shadowbox popup using js code? If not, take a look at the "Advanced" section of http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html. Once you understand that, it should be a simple matter of checking the hash value and deciding whether or not to show the popup.